# Multiplication of the numbers $1$ to $n$

Tags: arithmetic, factorial

Let's say I want to find  the product of $1,2,3, \dots, 10$. Do I need to do $1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot \dots \cdot 10$ manually or is there an easier way to do it?

Something like the sumation of  $1$ to $n$ which gives $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$.

I tried to search but couldn't find a way to do it directly.

Comment: This is just $10!$ or generally $n!.\,$ Many calculators have a button `n!` for the factorial.

Comment: Even I know this but I need an formula as I need to do this without calculator.

Comment: If you're trying to do permutations and combinations, note that $n P r = \frac{n!}{(n-r)!} = n (n-1) \ldots (n-r+1)$, and similarly for $n C r$. There isn't an easy way by hand without carrying out some multiplications (and the factorial grows _extremely_ quickly, so you can't compute it for modest values of $n$ by hand anyway), though for sufficiently large $n$, you can get a good approximation with Stirling's Approximation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation.

Answer (score 1):

It is known as factorial and denoted as $n!$.

The case $10!$ can be reduced:

\begin{eqnarray}
1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdots \cdot 8 \cdot 9 \cdot 10 &=& 10 \Big(5-4\Big) \Big(5-3\Big) \cdots \Big(5+4\Big)\\
&=& 50 \Big(25-16\Big) \Big(25-9\Big) \Big(25-4\Big) \Big(25-1\Big)\\
&=& 50 \Big(15-6\Big) \Big(15+6\Big) \Big(20-4\Big)  \Big(20+4\Big)\\
&=& 50 \Big(225 - 36\Big) \Big(400 - 16\Big)\\
&=& 50 \times 189 \times 384 = 3,628,800
\end{eqnarray}

---

If you have to do it by head, collect easy factors:

\begin{eqnarray}
1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdot 5 \cdot 6 \cdot 7 \cdot 8 \cdot 9 \cdot 10 &=&
\Big( 2 \cdot 4 \cdot 5 \cdot 10 \Big) \Big( 3 \cdot 6 \cdot 8 \cdot 9 \Big) \cdot 7\\
&=& 20^2 \cdot 6^4 \cdot 7\\
&=& 400 \times 1296 \times 7
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: It is known as "factorial". "Faculty" seems to be a literal translation from dutch.

Comment: Yep - sorry... Did corrected it...

Comment: I thought there would be formula like there is for summation. Isn't there formula for this ?

Comment: There is no formula, only a reduction as I showed it.

Comment: @keen: I added another line to do the calculation without calculator.

Comment: It's not only about number 10. I needed to do it for it any number.

Comment: Given another number you expect...

Comment: For large n, use stirlings approximation

Answer (score 0):

The fact that there is a special notation for the factorial suggests that there is no simpler formula for it other than the definition.

Note that there is no special notation for $\sum_{i=1}^n i$, since it can be written as $n(n+1)/2$. (I'm not sure $\binom{n+1}{2}$ counts as special notation in this context.)

If you need a formula, you could use $n! = \Gamma(n+1)$, but using $n!$ is probably much clearer.

Comment: ..."there is *not* a simpler formula"...

Comment: @Winther, fixed, thanks.